# Как перебрать элементы объекта?

Tags: javascript

Есть JSON: `{"Gray":"11","Black":"18"}`.

Как его перебирать циклом так, чтобы можно было использовать ключ и значение?
(key => value, как в цикле foreach на php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Данный пример: `{"Gray":"11","Black":"18"}`

является объектом, для обхода свойств объекта можно воспользоваться циклом [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). При этом будут проверены **все** перечисляемые свойства, включая свойства предков

```js
var o = {
  "Gray": "11",
  "Black": "18"
};

for (var key in o) {
  console.log(key, ':', o[key]);
}
```

Кроме того, можно воспользоваться функцией [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var o = {
  "Gray": "11",
  "Black": "18"
};

Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, ':', this[key]);
}, o);
```

Comment: Спасибо. То что искал

Answer (score 4):

Лучше использовать функцию jquery $.each

```
$.each(JSON.parse('{"Gray":"11","Black":"18"}'), function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + " " + value); 
})
```

Comment: нет не лучше, во-первых, в вопросе нет упоминания jQuery, поэтому данный под может быть не применен в принципе, во-вторых, внутри себя он используется тот же самый _for..in_

Comment: нету да, но пользоваться удобнее

Comment: чем именно удобнее?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var json = '{"Gray":"11","Black":"18"}';

// Конвертируем JSON в объект
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

// Работаем с объектом
for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop, obj[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

используйте конструкцию `for..in`

```
var data =  {"Gray":"11","Black":"18"};
for (color in data)
  alert("Color: " + color + ", Value: " + data[color];
```